# Сдвиг ячеек в шаблоне bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, шаблоны

Использую вот такой код. Но когда заголовок длинный, ячейки сдвигаются вниз. 
Как этого можно избежать?

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
            </a>
            <h3>
                <a href="#">Project Name</a>
            </h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
            </a>
            <h3>
                <a href="#">Project Namefg dg dsfg sdgsd gdf s </a>
            </h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
            </a>
            <h3>
                <a href="#">Project Name</a>
            </h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
        </div>
             <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
            </a>
            <h3>
                <a href="#">Project Name</a>
            </h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
        </div>
             <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
            </a>
            <h3>
                <a href="#">Project Name</a>
            </h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
        </div>
             <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
            </a>
            <h3>
                <a href="#">Project Name</a>
            </h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

`col-md-4` - это 1/3 строки.

И дело не в заголовке - когда поместишь разный текст, эффект будет такой же.

Можно (любой из вариантов):

- помещать по 3 элемента в строку
- задать элементам одинаковую высоту
- каждому третьему сделать clear:both (современные браузеры)
- использовать display:inline-block вместо float, не забыв убрать пробельные символы между элементами
- использовать flexbox для размещения и переноса (современные браузеры)

Comment: дело в том, что я буду выводить циклом элементы, и поэтому у всех будет один стиль. и мне нужно выводить по три материала на строку. как это лучше сделать?

Comment: Я 5 вариантов предложил, что можно сделать. А ты даже требуемые браузеры не назвал.

Comment: после каждого третьего элемента `<div class="clearfix"></div>` еще так можно

Comment: @xaja, а зачем лишний div?

Answer (score 0):

в этом случае помогает `box-sizing:border-box;` в css

Comment: спасибо. но не совсем понял как это использовать

Comment: И как же он помогает? float переностися туда, где помещается, т. е. при более выском втором элементе за ним будут расположены 2 более низких.